# Koszul resolution with wrong dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be the zero locus of $e_1, \dots, e_n$ sections of a vector bundle $\mathcal{E}$ of rank $r$ on $Y$. Assume that the codimension of $X$ is strictly less than $n$, then the Koszul complex associated to the sections is not exact. What can be said about the cohomologies of this complex in general? Are there nice cases in which, even though the complex is not exact, the cohomologies can be known?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $X$ is a locally complete intersection of codimension $m < n$. Then the natural morphism
$$
E^\vee|_X \to I_X \otimes O_X = I_X/I_X^2 = N^\vee_{X/Y}
$$
is surjective, let $F$ be its kernel (it is a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $n - m$). Then
$$
H_i(Kosz(E,e)) \cong \wedge^iF.
$$

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but shouldn't the map you wrote be zero? It is defined in terms of the sections $e_1, \dots, e_n$ and by the definition they vanish on $X$ and you're restricting the map to $X$.

Comment: No, it is not zero. The resulting map to the conormal bundle is given by the differentials of the $e_i$.

Comment: I see, thank you. Another question: are you considering $\Lambda^i F$ as a sheaf on $Y$ via the pushforward? The point is that the cohomology sheaves will be annihilated by the action of $I_X$ and therefore it's enough to recover them as modules on $Y$, is it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, $\wedge^iF$ is considered as a sheaf on $Y$ via pushforward.